# "pcadapt", "installation of package ‘bigutilsr’ had non-zero exit status"

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm trying to install the pcadapt in RStudio using

```
> remotes::install_github("bcm-uga/pcadapt")
```

But it gives me the error installation of package ‘bigutilsr’ had non-zero exit status

```
Downloading GitHub repo bcm-uga/pcadapt@master
Installing 1 packages: bigutilsr
Installing package into ‘/home/jenifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
probando la URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/bigutilsr_0.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 915116 bytes (893 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 893 KB

* installing *source* package ‘bigutilsr’ ...
** package ‘bigutilsr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/jenifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/jenifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ogk.cpp -o ogk.o
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/jenifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rollmean.cpp -o rollmean.o
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/jenifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rowSumsSq.cpp -o rowSumsSq.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o bigutilsr.so RcppExports.o ogk.o rollmean.o rowSumsSq.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/jenifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/bigutilsr/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘eigs.matrix’, ‘eigs.dgeMatrix’, ‘eigs.dgCMatrix’, ‘eigs.dgRMatrix’, ‘eigs.dsyMatrix’, ‘eigs.dsCMatrix’, ‘eigs.dsRMatrix’, ‘eigs.function’, ‘eigs_sym.matrix’, ‘eigs_sym.dgeMatrix’, ‘eigs_sym.dgCMatrix’, ‘eigs_sym.dgRMatrix’, ‘eigs_sym.function’, ‘svds.matrix’, ‘svds.dgeMatrix’, ‘svds.dgCMatrix’, ‘svds.dgRMatrix’, ‘svds.dsyMatrix’, ‘svds.dsCMatrix’, ‘svds.dsRMatrix’, ‘svds.function’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘RSpectra.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘bigutilsr’
* removing ‘/home/jenifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/bigutilsr’
Error: Failed to install 'pcadapt' from GitHub:
  (convertido del aviso) installation of package ‘bigutilsr’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

I've been searching on google and it seems that if gcc isn't set up correctly, then R tries to compile the packages and it fails (https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-any-packages-non-zero-exit-status/53310), but I don't know if this is the case, and if it is, I don't know how to solve it.

```
gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
```

I'm also having similar issues while trying to install adegenet, hierfstat, pegas, poppr and other packages but I will put a post about this with moor details somewhere else ins stackoverflow just to keep it simple and to not give place to confussion with the code.

If somebody can help me, I will appreciate it very much
Cheers

Comment: Can you work out this problem: "shared object ‘RSpectra.so’ not found" ?  Does the `RSpectra` package load?  If not, can you reinstall it?

Comment: "install.packages ("RSpectra")" gives me "installation of package ‘RSpectra’ had non-zero exit status". And I don't know how to install it